# Excel VBA webscrape, how do i get span values?

Tags: excel, vba, web-scraping

Relatively new to VBA and new to web scraping.  I've been tasked to get some data from a website.  I've tried searching on here for help, tried lots of permutations based on what I found but not getting the results I need.
A snippet from the webpage DOM Explorer (using "F12 Developer Tools") shows the the below (edited to make it generic):

```
<div class=”nav nav-list”>
<div>
<span class=”nav-list-item”>Item:</span>
        <span>
            mySearchString and other text
        </span>
</div>
<div>…</div>
<div>
        <span class=”nav-list-item”>Retail UPC:</span>
        <span>upcNumber</span>
</div>
<div>…</div>
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to search for "mySearchString", extracting "and other text" and searching for "Retail UPC:" & extracting "upcNumber".

Tried using nested if statements but can't get any to work.  Below is a snippet of the latest version of what i've been playing with:

```
Dim harborDesc() as String
Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Set ieObj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")    
Dim htmlEle As Object
Dim itemurl As String

Itemurl = “url of interest”
ieObj.navigate itemurl    'in this case, the web page is has the same name as the itemNum
Do While ieObj.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE  'wait by repeating loop until ready
Loop

For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list-item")
                harborDesc = Split(htmlEle.innerText, htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText)
Next htmlEle
```

Thanks in advance for any tips/help

Comment: What happens when you run your code?

Comment: run-time error 91 "Object variable or With block variable not set"
Been beating my head on it for hours trying different things

Comment: On which line ?

Comment: It's possible the elements you want to access are built dynamically after the page has loaded (readyState only checks for complete delivery of the page itself - it doesn't take into account any script-driven actions which might take place after that), in which case you'll need to add a "wait" before trying to query for them.

Comment: I think it is fully loaded.  The error is on this line:

harborDesc = Split(htmlEle.innerText, htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("span")(1).innerText)

When I inspect the page elements it appears fully loaded.  
Another problem, which would help me work on the problem locally instead of a page I have to be logged into, is how do I access an already open page instead of creating a new instance?

Comment: I think it is fully loaded because when I look at the page elements (by using "F12 Developer Tools") I see the "mySearchString and other text" I have shown in my initial post asking my questions.  Should I be checking using a different method.  Thanks

Comment: Can you share an URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set up a nodeList and loop them hunting for your search terms.

The nodeList is generated from a css query with Or syntax that means you will get

```
<span class="nav-list-item">
```

but also match those elements which are span tag [adjacent sibling](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator) e.g.

```
<span class="nav-list-item">Retail UPC:</span> 
<span>upcNumber</span>
```

[image]

You use `Instr` on the `.innerText` to match for your first search term. Then, if found, use `Replace` to remove the matched text and leave the remainder as specified in your question.

If you find `Retail UPC` at a given index then `upcNumber` should be at the next index.

---

**VBA:**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub FindInfo()
    Const SEARCH_TERM1 As String = "mySearchString"
    Const SEARCH_TERM2 As String = "Retail UPC:"
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, searchTermCandidates As Object
    Dim i As Long, index As Long, ieObj As InternetExplorer
    Set ieObj = New InternetExplorer
    With ieObj
        .Visible = True
        .Navigate2 "url"

        While .Busy Or .readyState < 4: DoEvents: Wend

        Set html = .document

        Set searchTermCandidates = html.querySelectorAll("span.nav-list-item, span.nav-list-item + span")
        For i = 0 To searchTermCandidates.Length - 1
            If InStr(searchTermCandidates.item(i).innerText, SEARCH_TERM1) > 0 Then
                Debug.Print Replace$(searchTermCandidates.item(i).innerText, SEARCH_TERM1, vbNullString)
            End If
            If searchTermCandidates.item(i).innerText = SEARCH_TERM2 Then
                Debug.Print searchTermCandidates.item(i + 1).innerText
            End If
        Next
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks so much to Tate & QHarr for all the help.  My experience is mostly with matlab, fortran, excel, etc, only a little C & little VBA but totally new to web scraping so the above question had been a struggle for hours - apologies for any slowness on my part.  I wasn't even sure what to search on and will change the title to be more useful if i can.

QHarr, your solution worked however the querySelectorAll returned Null results until i changed to "Dim html as Object" instead of HTMLDocument.  Then it worked great.  Thank you very much, would not have got there without your input!

Comment: No worries. Html as object is late bound whereas htmldocument requires reference to Microsoft html object library. You don’t actually need to set to an htmldocument variable as you can work directly off ie.document e.g. ie.document.querySelectorAll

Answer (score 0):

It's possible that `htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("span")(1)` is attempting to return an array of  elements where there is only 1 and thus the only returnable value of that array would be located in the first spot of the array `htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("span")(0)`.

Also, the way you're using `Split()` isn't making sense to me. The parameters for `Split()` are `Split(expression, [ delimiter, [ limit, [ compare ]]])` meaning the `.innertext` of the `<span>` element you're looking for would be the delimiter? Also, I don't see anywhere where `harborDesc` is defined as an array of appropriate size (or any size) in the first place, which is likely why your `Error 91` is occurring, as `Split()` needs an array in order to accept values.

**EDIT:**

Adding this from my comments.

If what you want is the text from the `<span>` innertext, you should be doing something like

```
Dim harborDesc() As String
Redim harborDesc(0 to 1) 
For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list-item") 
    Redim Preserve harborDesc(0 to UBound(harborDesc) + 1)
    harborDesc(UBound(harborDesc) - 1) = htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("span")(0).innerText
Next htmlEle
```

**EDIT 2:**

If you're having trouble locating the "span" elements, maybe you're finding a matching "nav-list-item" class where no "span" element exists. In that case, it would be worthwhile to create a nested `For-Loop` to test for that such as

```
Dim ieObj As InternetExplorer
Set ieObj = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")    
Dim htmlEle As Object
Dim spanEle as Object
Dim itemurl As String

Itemurl = “url of interest”
ieObj.navigate itemurl    'in this case, the web page is has the same name as the itemNum
Do While ieObj.readyState <> READYSTATE_COMPLETE  'wait by repeating loop 
until ready
Loop

For Each htmlEle In ieObj.document.getElementsByClassName("nav-list-item")
    For Each spanEle in htmlEle.getElementsByTagName("span")
        Debug.Print spanEle.innertext
    Next spanEle
Next htmlEle
```

Comment: oops, forgot to include my dimensioning statement for harborDesc.  I defined it as

Comment: I've added the Dim statement to show it in my code snippet at the top.  As an example.  The below statement sets harborDesc to "Item:"

    harborDesc = htmlEle.innerText

Comment: Gotcha. So, harborDesc needs to be an array to accept values from a Split() function. See [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)
Secondly, your "delimiter" parameter is not going to net you anything valuable.

Comment: Added to my answer

Comment: Thanks Tate, sadly that gives a syntax error on your third line of code

Comment: The Redim Preserve statement? Sorry, I had a horrible brain fart and forgot to include the lower bound in the Redim statement. Try it now, I've fixed it.

Comment: Still gave me an index out of bounds error.  Let me try to simplify my original question: based on the below, I'm trying to extract stringB, not stringA:
    <div class=”nav nav-list”>
    <div>
    <span class=”nav-list-item”>stringA</span>
            <span>
                stringB
            </span>
    </div>

Comment: oops, i seem to be failing at adding code.  My excuses, new to this site & tired.  trying again:
<div class=”nav nav-list”>
<div>
<span class=”nav-list-item”>stringA</span>
        <span>
            stringB
        </span>
</div>